# Compiling Mongod with SSL Support

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to compile mongod.exe from github src but I keep running into the following error:

```
C:\Github\Mongo>scons --64 --ssl mongod.exe
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.3.4
python version: 2 7 8 'final' 0
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking whether the C compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking if C++ compiler "$CC" is MSVC... (cached) yes
Checking if C compiler "cl" is MSVC... (cached) yes
Checking if C compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or newer...(cach
ed) yes
Checking if C++ compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or newer...(ca
ched) yes
Checking if target architecture is 32-bit x86...(cached) no
Checking if we are using libstdc++... (cached) no
Checking if we are on a POSIX system... (cached) no
Checking for __declspec(thread)... (cached) no
Checking for C++11 <atomic> support... (cached) no
Checking for C++ header file execinfo.h... (cached) no
Checking for C library pcap... (cached) no
Checking for C library wpcap... (cached) no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fobuild\win32\64\ssl\mongo\db\db.obj /c src\mongo\db\db.cpp /TP /nologo /EHs
c /W3 /wd4355 /wd4800 /wd4267 /wd4244 /wd4290 /wd4068 /wd4351 /we4099 /Z7 /error
Report:none /MT /O2 /Oy- /Gw /Gy /Zc:inline /DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D_SCONS /DMONGO_
EXPOSE_MACROS /DSUPPORT_UTF8 /DMONGO_OPTIMIZED_BUILD /DMONGO_BYTE_ORDER=1234 /D_
UNICODE /DUNICODE /D_CONSOLE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /DMONGO_SSL /D_WIN32_WINN
T=0x0502 /DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05020200 /IC:\Github\winpcap\Include /Isrc\third_part
y\s2 /Isrc\third_party\pcre-8.30 /Isrc\third_party\boost /Ibuild\win32\64\ssl /I
src /Z7
db.cpp
C:\Github\Mongo\src\mongo/platform/atomic_intrinsics.h(60) : fatal error C1189:
#error :  "Windows builds must use a compiler supporting std::atomic"
scons: *** [build\win32\64\ssl\mongo\db\db.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The source code throwing the error shows a variable _WIN32 as being defined and set to True but I thought the --64 option would have set this to false?

Any suggestions on how to resolve to complete a SSL build would be appreciated:

Environment: Visual Studio 2013, Window 7, x64 latest master from github

Observation: C++11 support is available when I run scons without --ssl and the compilation proceeds, but when using --ssl options the C++11 (atomic) supported is equal to "no" and the compilation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if OpenSSL is not found during the build process.

- Make sure to install the latest version of [OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) (Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1j)
- When compiling add the home path of OpenSSL with --extrapath

Example build command:

> scons --ssl --release --64 --extrapath=<OPENSSL-HOME> core